# WebPack Browsersync with MAMP not loading the same CSS

Tags: laravel, webpack, mamp, browser-sync, laravel-mix

I'm running a Laravel site with MAMP Pro and it is working fine but when I launch the site with `npm run watch` the site will load and so will the css but the actual styling looks broken in comparison to the just MAMP site. Comparing the two I can see that styles are missing on the `npm run watch` site.

My Laravel Mix script:

```
mix.sourceMaps(true, "source-map")
    .js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .options({
        postCss: [require("lost"), require("autoprefixer")]
    })
    .browserSync({
        proxy: "My MAMP URL",
        browser: "google chrome"
    });
```